# Passing strings for execution in Fortran subroutines

Tags: string, fortran, fortran90, subroutine

In the following subroutine I would like to pass a string variables named `str`. If it is `'poly'`, `'gaus'`, `'slat'`, then it has a predefined action (`fval =` *see code below* ). I would like to have the user specify a function to use and pass that as a string variable.

That is ...

If `str = '3*cos(i*t)'`, then i would like to have `fval` be equal to `3*cos(i*t)`. How can I get Fortran to interpret the string entered as a command to be executed by Fortran?

```
subroutine f(fval, i, t, str)
implicit none
integer, parameter :: ikind = selected_int_kind(8)
integer, parameter :: dbl = selected_real_kind(15,307)

integer(kind = ikind) :: i
real(kind = dbl) :: fval, t
character str*100

if(str .eq. 'poly') then
    fval = t**i
elseif(str .eq. 'slat') then
    fval = exp(-i*t)
elseif(str .eq. 'gaus') then
    fval = exp(-i*t*t)
else
    fval = ???
endif

end subroutine
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't.  not easily.  there are two things you can do, though:

- first, you can use function pointers.  there's a simple example at http://www.macresearch.org/advanced_fortran_90_callbacks_with_the_transfer_function - the idea is that you can pass the name of a function defined elsewhere.  that may be enough to solve your problem.
- you can call a library that parses the string and evaluates the expression.  i don't know of anything in fortran, but your fortran compiler may support calling c routines.  for gfortran (and maybe others), this looks like it would work - http://www.gnu.org/s/libmatheval/ (example fortran code at http://www.gnu.org/s/libmatheval/manual/libmatheval.html#Fortran-sample-program)

Comment: I would suggest to use Lua, which is easily compiled along your Fortran application and could be used to evaluate strings. Maybe https://bitbucket.org/haraldkl/aotus/overview might give you an idea how this could be done.

Comment: i don't think option one would work. it's the "defined elsewhere" that is the problem. i would like this to work for ANY function which is entered as a string. as for your second option - i think this may be exactly what i am looking for!

Answer (score -4):

Actually, it's really simple

`subroutine f(fval, i, t, str)
   ...
   character(len=*), intent(in) :: str
   ...
end subroutine`

The trick is to define the dummy string argument as of "unknown length" BUT with the `intent(in)` modifier.

Comment: I think closer attention to the question would show that this is not an answer.  The question solicits solutions to the problem of parsing a string for the mathematical expression it contains.