# Compiling Fortran code from the R interpreter

Tags: r, fortran, ode

I am looking into running crucial loops in my R code in Fortran. I found plenty of resources on *calling compiled Fortran subroutines* in R, but nothing about *calling Fortran code compilation* from R.

The reason I ask is I am building an efficient ODE solver for equations rife with arrays; so I need to feed the model equations to the Fortran solver in one way or another. I considered trying to pass a string with the model equations to the Fortran subroutine to than evaluate, but then I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326828/passing-strings-for-execution-in-fortran-subroutines/) stating this is quite difficult, so I would rather find a different solution if possible.

Any other creative solutions are welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [inline](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=inline) package.  From the beginning of the examples section for `cfunction()`:

```
## A simple Fortran example
code <- "
      integer i
      do 1 i=1, n(1)
    1 x(i) = x(i)**3
"
cubefn <- cfunction(signature(n="integer", x="numeric"), 
                    code, convention=".Fortran")

cubefn(n, x)$x
```