# How to handle a complicated function expression generated by Mathematica in Fortran?

Tags: function, file, fortran

I am doing an integration of an extremely long expression of a function which was in `FortranForm`. I have saved the expression in a file named `Expression.m`. I make the statement as below, no compile mistake. when I run the executive file then I get Fortran runtime error: Bad real number in item 1 of list input . I still haven't found where it goes wrong?

```
program test
implicit none

integer :: j, divisions
real :: ix, I, function
real :: step

divisions = 100000.
step = 1. / divisions
I = 0.
do j = 0, divisions
ix = (j + 0.5) * step 
I = I + function(ix) * step
end do 
print *, I
end program test

function function(x) result(expr)
real :: x , expr 
open(1, file = 'Expression.m', status = 'old')
read(1,*) expr
close(1)
end function function
```

[my problem have been solved](https://github.com/ComplicatedPhenomenon/Fortran_practice/issues/2).

Comment: Read the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326828/passing-strings-for-execution-in-fortran-subroutines/7327010#7327010, in particular the second part of the answer.  A `FortranForm` expression is still a string.  The straightforward way to incorporate it into a Fortran program is to paste it into the source file and include it in the compilation.  If it's too long then break it down.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: I closed it as a duplicates. The comments above explain what you meant and the answer is you cannot simply read a function expression in Fortran. You need to code it or use a much more complicated evaluation system.

Comment: Just a note, some languages *do* allow such evaluation, but not classical compiled languages like Fortran or C, but dynamic languages like LISP, Python and many others.

Comment: Note that in the linked github thread Szagi was also very confused first and required a lot of clarification. On StackOverflow one cannot have a discussion so we need the question to be edited into a clear form from the beginning to be able to answer.

Comment: To be clear, I in my previous comment I did not request any further edits to this question. Questions should not normally contain an answer. What should potentially be edited is the **question**, the explanation of the problem, not the solution.